# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.mshtml

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, mshtml

I have just published my asp.net web application in vs2008

THe first page displays nicely but pressing the submit button to get to the next page triggers:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have included the mshtml assembly in the bin folder. I don't understand what's wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your project in solution explorer > Add Reference > Select proper dll > OK
2. Now, you can see your dll in Bin folder in solution explorer.
   Make sure, you have selected proper version of dll as referenced in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set "Copy Local" for the assembly reference in Visual Studio?

Comment: No :/ How do I set that please